# In angularJS, how to find document for myApp.value()?

Tags: angularjs

I have problem in finding document for specific function in Angularjs.

When I am reading the document for [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), there is a snippet using .value()

```
angular.module('myStatefulFilterApp', [])
.filter('decorate', ['decoration', function(decoration) {

  function decorateFilter(input) {
    return decoration.symbol + input + decoration.symbol;
  }
  decorateFilter.$stateful = true;

  return decorateFilter;
}])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'decoration', function($scope, decoration) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
  $scope.decoration = decoration;
}])
.value('decoration', {symbol: '*'}); // this value()
```

Can you help me find the document for this .value() on https://docs.angularjs.org?

I can see .value is at same level as .controller, .directive, .filter, so it should be attached to angular.Module object, but here is the [doc for angular.Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module). I can't find anything. Myabe I made wrong assumption or don't fully understand the conventions in Angularjs field.

I want to know how to find .value() on https://docs.angularjs.org. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  The documentation for `value(name, object);` is *definitely* on the page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module that you linked.

Comment: @Claies  Sorry, I failed to see it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would find the documentation under [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value), as value is one type of provider, same as directives and services.

Value is one of the provider-recipies, and is used to create a simple value that can be injected through dependency injection. It is usefull for things like a global config-object.

Comment: I got it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide , not in the $provider developer guide link, but thanks providing me a direction. I am still not very clear about how the angular documents is organized.

Comment: thats a better link. I'll update my answer with that link instead. I usully use google with the `site:angularjs.org` filter to find things on that site.